# Bi-linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Prove that bi-linear function $f:M_n(\mathbb{C})\times M_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined as $f(A,B)=Tr(A^t\overline{B})$ is non-singular.

I don't quite know where to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$, $B=(b_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$. Then
$$f(A,B) = a_{ij}\overline{b_{ij}}$$
with summation over repeated indices. Now you should be able to differentiate the function.

Comment: Uh?? The definition of $\;f\;$ is definitely not what you wrote there...or, of course, I'm misunderstanding something bad.

Comment: @DonAntonio Recall to sum over repeated indices. You have $(AB)_{kl}=a_{ki}b_{il}$, transposition exchanges the indices, conjugation is, well, conjugation and $tr(A)=a_{ii}$.

Comment: Exactly, @Daniel: it must be *sum* over same repeated indexes !

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;E_{km}\in M_n(\Bbb C)\;$ be the matrix all of which entries are zero **except** the entry $\;km\;$ , which is $\;1\;$ . It's easy to check $\;\{ E_{km}\}_{1\le k,m\le n}\;$ is a basis for the complex space $\;M_n(\Bbb C)\;$ .

We have that $\;E_{km}^t=E_{mk}\;,\;\;\overline{E_{km}}=E_{km}\;$ , so

$$F\left(E_{km},E_{rs}\right)=tr.\left(E_{km}^t\overline{E_{rs}}\right)=tr.\left(E_{mk}E_{rs}\right)=$$

$$=tr.\left(\begin{cases}0&,\;\;k\neq r\\{}\\E_{ms}&,\;\;k=r\end{cases}\right)=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;k\neq r\;or\;m\neq s\\{}\\1&,\;\;k=r\;and\;m=s\end{cases}$$

Now check the matrix of $\;f\;$ wrt the above basis is regular...